# Mathematica9: NDSolve slows down after repeated calls

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, numerical-integration, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 11.0.1**

---

I have noted that in *Mathematica* 9 my code, which involves a lot of calls to `NDSolve`, slows down considerably after some time.

Apparently, the problem is `NDSolve` itself and it seems to be related to *Mathematica* 9, as the following example shows:

```
RunNDSolve :=  Timing[Do[NDSolve[{f''[x] == -f[x], f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0},
  {f[x]}, {x, 0, 1}], {1000}]][[1]]
```

`RunNDSolve` integrates a simple differential equation 1000 times using `NDSolve` and returns the time needed to carry out the integrations.

In *Mathematica* 9, `RunNDSolve` takes longer and longer times as it is called again, as the following example shows:

```
Table[{j, RunNDSolve}, {j, 50}]
```

In *Mathematica* 9 (extract of the full result):

```
j, RunNDSolve
1, 0.712
10, 2.649000
20, 4.869000
30, 7.326000
50, 13.372000
```

In *Mathematica* 8 (extract of the full result):

```
j, RunNDSolve
1, 0.5880000000000001`
10, 0.593`
20, 0.5719999999999992`
30, 0.5670000000000002`
40, 0.5770000000000017`
50, 0.5850000000000009`
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be and how to fix it?

Comment: Using your code I can reproduce the increasing timing pattern in version 9, and the constant timings in versions 7 and 8. I haven't thought yet about why this might be though.

Comment: I've run into similar issues with an earlier version of Mathematica, perhaps version 6. It showed up when solving very large systems of ODEs with `NDSolve`.

Comment: @Pillsy, what makes you believe it was the same cause? Could you send an example?

Comment: I have filed this as a bug. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: I have found the same problem on INTEL i7 and XEON machines. This needs to be fixed by Wolfram. gamma3142, what computer system did you use to obtain your Mathematica 8 results? Its seems to be very powerful.

Comment: @user13754 Please, post this as a comment, not as a answer.

Comment: @user13754 This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @user13754 This is not an official Wolfram site.  We are just users like you.  If this bug affects you then the best thing you can do is contact Wolfram support and complain about it, which I guess might help prioritize this problem.

Answer (score 8):

I also can confirm this (Windows7, Version 9 only), it looks like a nasty bug to me that seems to be related to using the second derivative. As a workaround you can do a classical reformulation (spoiling much of the advantages of using Mathematica, though) to avoid second derivatives:

```
RunNDSolve := Timing[Do[
  NDSolve[{f'[x] == fp[x], fp'[x] == -f[x], f[0] == 1, 
  fp[0] == 0}, {fp[x], f[x]}, {x, 0, 1}], 
  {1000}]][[1]]
```

which seems to not have the problem and gives the same result. Another workaround which will be more useful in practical applications seems to be to localize your dependent variables, e.g.:

```
RunNDSolve := Module[{f}, Timing[Do[
 NDSolve[{f''[x] == -f[x], f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0}, {f[x]}, {x, 0, 
   1}], {1000}]][[1]]]
```

`Block` will work just as well, but be aware of the differences between the two. Actually I was very surprised that I haven't suffered from this problem as that's what I've everywhere in my codes but there I usually localize the dependent variables which seems to explain why I have never had problems with this...

It's probably worth noting that using the new names reserved for formal variables as e.g. `\[FormalF]` which could be used as an alternative for localized variables do -- not surprising -- also show the performance problem.

I suggest you send a bug report to wolfram support.

Comment: Hi Albert, I filed this as a bug. Thanks for the hints about possible causes.

Comment: @user21 Did you get any clarity in this matter? The problem appears to still exist as of V10.0.0.0?

Comment: just tried it and it looks like the problem still exists in version 10

Comment: @AlbertRetey  Problem persists for "10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)".  `Timing` grows more or less linearly.  `ClearSystemCache[]` does not help.  Neither does closing and reopening the notebook.  Of course, restarting Mathematica does.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: that is sad to hear (with user21 having filed a bug I think WRI is aware of it). Have you tried the workarounds? I could imagine that they consider that to only be a minor problem when using localized variables solves it...

Comment: @AlbertRetey  Because I am not having this problem myself, I have not tried your work-arounds.