# Bug in NDSolve (Mathematica 9.0.1)?

Tags: functions

The following code performs many times the same identical operation, but the time it takes increases systematically. This seems to be a problem of Mathematica 9.0.1 and above. Mathematica 9.0.0 does not have this problem. Do you know how to fix this? Perhaps using the `Method` option?

```
Clear[delta];
delta := NDSolve[{y''[n] + y'[n] - y[n] == 0, y[-3] == 1.,y'[-3] == 1.}, y, {n, -3, 0}];
Do[{
time = Timing[Do[delta, {a, 1000}]];
Print[time]
}, {i, 10}]
```

Comment: or duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30494/7167) not sure which one is better to link to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Version
```

> "9.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 24, 2013)"

```
Clear[delta];
delta := NDSolve[{
    y''[n] + y'[n] - y[n] == 0,
    y[-3] == 1., y'[-3] == 1.},
   y, {n, -3, 0}];
Do[
 Print[
  Timing[
   Table[
     (y /. delta[[1]])[-2], {1000}] //
    Union]],
 {i, 10}]
```

> {1.743167,{2.13832}}
>
> {2.285117,{2.13832}}
>
> {2.801171,{2.13832}}
>
> {3.340376,{2.13832}}
>
> {3.878951,{2.13832}}
>
> {4.426765,{2.13832}}
>
> {4.997985,{2.13832}}
>
> {5.558735,{2.13832}}
>
> {6.112288,{2.13832}}
>
> {6.662651,{2.13832}}

Use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` so that you only solve the equation once.

```
Clear[delta];
delta = NDSolve[{
    y''[n] + y'[n] - y[n] == 0,
    y[-3] == 1., y'[-3] == 1.},
   y, {n, -3, 0}];
Do[
 Print[
  Timing[
   Table[
     (y /. delta[[1]])[-2], {1000}] //
    Union]],
 {i, 10}]
```

> {0.007109,{2.13832}}
>
> {0.007204,{2.13832}}
>
> {0.007366,{2.13832}}
>
> {0.007139,{2.13832}}
>
> {0.006914,{2.13832}}
>
> {0.007126,{2.13832}}
>
> {0.007045,{2.13832}}
>
> {0.007172,{2.13832}}
>
> {0.007201,{2.13832}}
>
> {0.007057,{2.13832}}